# how to combine cut command with arithmetic comparison

Tags: shell, awk, cut

Good morning all,

I have a file called `test.txt`

```
audit.log.20140612:6/11/14 6:27:33 AM;SUCCESS;998ms;10.62.172.52;52750;Issue
audit.log.20140612:6/11/14 6:28:25 AM;SUCCESS;580ms;10.62.172.52;52750;Issue;
audit.log.20140612:6/11/14 6:28:25 AM;SUCCESS;500ms;10.62.172.52;52750;Issue;
audit.log.20140612:6/11/14 6:28:25 AM;SUCCESS;58ms;10.62.172.52;52750;Issue;
```

Now I wanted to extract all the line which have more than 100ms(milli seconds).

I achieved till getting 3rd field form following command,

```
cut -d ';' -f 3 test.txt
```

Now I want to pipe this results to some shell command so that i can compare the results. where the `time is > 100ms`

Finally my output should be,

```
audit.log.20140612:6/11/14 6:27:33 AM;SUCCESS;998ms;10.62.172.52;52750;Issue
audit.log.20140612:6/11/14 6:28:25 AM;SUCCESS;580ms;10.62.172.52;52750;Issue;
audit.log.20140612:6/11/14 6:28:25 AM;SUCCESS;500ms;10.62.172.52;52750;Issue;
```

Comment: not possible in shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '$3+0 > 100' yourfile
```

With `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                      
while read line; do 
        fields=(${line//;/ });
        t=${fields[4]}; 
        if [ ${t%ms} -gt 100 ]; 
        then 
                echo "$line"; 
        fi; 
done< yourfile
```

Comment: While comparing it will convert the `58ms` to `58`. After that, you can do the arithmatic comparison.

Comment: Much more elegant and compact than what I came up with: awk -F';' '{time=substr($3,match($3,/[0-9]+/),RLENGTH); if(int(time) > 100){ print $0; } }' test.txt

Comment: `+0` is often seen in `awk` commands to extract numbers from a field. But it does not work if text are in front of numbers like `more76`.  The you can use `sub(/[[:alpha:]]*/,"",$1` to get rid of text.

Comment: @run, Updated the `bash` solution too.